# How to make HTML Table accept integers with comma and dot separators

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make `<td>`-s in HTML Table accept integers with comma and dot separators?

```js
function getOrderProductInfo() {
  var table = $("#edit_print_costs_table_body");
  var year = parseInt($("#existing_seasons_input_field").val(), 10);
  var season = $("#existing_seasons_input").val();
  $.get("@(Url.Action("
    GetOrderProduktInfo ", "
    MaillingOrder "))" + '?year=' + year + '&season=' + season,
    function(resp) {
      var result = resp.Value;
      if (result.length > 0) {
        table.html("");
        result.forEach(function(v) {
          table.append("<tr id = '" + v.ID + "'><td>" + v.Amount + "</td ><td> " + v.PricePerUnit + "</td ><td>" + v.TotalPrice + "</td><td><button class='editButtonProduct'>edit</button></td> <td><button class='deleteButtonProduct'>Delete</button></td></tr > ");
        });
      } else {

      }
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "accept"? Is there anything not working when you write these integers to your markup?

Comment: @Nico Haase yes when I unput the numbers with dot or comma separators like: 2.5 or 2,678 only the part before dot and comma appear.

Comment: Please share more details, like the markup involved. Why is this question tagged with Javascript, but does not contain any such code?

Comment: make integer to toString() and then add in table

Comment: @NicoHaase I added the code for getting theat displayes the table with data but the one generatign the whole table is too big.

Comment: This looks more like a localization/internationalization issue while parsing and displaying inputs. Maybe have a look here to get some information https://phrase.com/blog/posts/step-step-guide-javascript-localization/

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase the code itself works fine but when I want to add comma or dot separated numbers it deletes everything after coa and dot. I don't know what to change or from which ange to aproach this.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, for example within a runnable example that triggers the problem. Also share your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Well, a table in html can contain a lot of things, especially (integer) numbers. Depending on local customs, the symbol (.) or (,) is used to denote something different (decimals or separate thousands). Regardless:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>3.14</td>
    <td>3,14</td>
    <td>300.124,124</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Should all work just fine! This just a guess though, since your question was not that clear on the circumstances you are working under.

Answer (score -1):

I guess that's impossible.
If it contains a comma or dot that means it isn't an integer.

Comment: how can I make the <td> accept the comma and dot separated numbers ? I believe the data sent is not an integer, but a string, the problem is that the guy who made this in on a vacation and won't be back for several weeks so I have none to ask.

Comment: "I guess" is really a guess. Seperating the numbers of an integer with a dot or comma to make them more readable is pretty common